# backbone.js: Retrieve a smaller version of model building a collection

Tags: performance, api, backbone.js

I'm trying to build an api to create a collection in backbone. My Model is called `log` and has this (shortened) properties (format for `getLog/<id>`):

```
{
    'id': string, 
    'duration': float, 
    'distance': float, 
    'startDate': string,
    'endDate': string
}
```

I need to create a collection, because I have many logs and I want to display them in a list. The api for creating the collection (`getAllLogs`) takes 30 sec to run, which is to slow. It returns the same as the format as the api `getLog/<id>`, but in an array, one element for each log on the database.

To speed things up, I rebuild the api several times and optimize it to it's limits, but now I came to 30 sec, which is still to slow.

My question is if it is possible to have a **collection filled with instances of a model without ALL the information in the model**, just a part of it needed to display the list. This will increase the speed of loading the collection and displaying the list, while in the background I could continue loading all other properties, or load them only for the elements I really need.

In my case, the model would load only with this information:

```
{
    'id': string, 
    'distance': float
}
```

and all other properties could be loaded later.

How can I do it? is it a good idea anyway?

thanks.

Comment: `if it is possible to have a collection filled with instances of a model without ALL the information in the model` -- of course it is.  Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: can you point me an example plz? I don't see it right now... thanks

Comment: Does my answer make any sense?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Do you want to get short models first and then have each model load it's own data after that?

Comment: @McGarnagle I now understand your inicial comment... after some time struggling around, I finally understood the essence of collections and models in backbone.  of course it is possible!!! DOH!

Comment: If getAllLogs takes 30 seconds and your app takes a little over 30 seconds, how does dropping fields in backbone speed up the app? You need to rework the API to either filter the results or paginate the results so you can start loading chunks of data right away.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `map` to get the shortened model.  Something like this will convert a `Backbone.Collection` "collection" with all properties to one with only "id" and "distance":

```
var shortCollection = new Backbone.Collection(collection.toJSON().map(function(x) { 
    return { id: x.id, distance: x.distance };
}));
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/LMaew/15/) a Fiddle illustration.